# How do I format lines from a text file in python

Tags: python, regex, parsing

Original txt file:

```
M:org.apache.mahout.math.list.IntArrayListTest:testReplaceFromToWith() (S)org.apache.mahout.math.list.IntArrayListTest:assertEquals(long,long)
M:org.apache.mahout.math.list.IntArrayListTest:testRetainAllSmall() (O)org.apache.mahout.math.list.IntArrayList:<init>()
M:org.apache.mahout.common.RandomUtilsTest:testNextTwinPrime() (S)org.apache.mahout.common.RandomUtils:nextTwinPrime(int)
M:org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenLongCharHashMapTest:testValues() (M)org.apache.mahout.math.list.CharArrayList:size()
```

I have over 50k lines like this in a text file, how do I read from the .txt file and format them to the format shown below with Python?

The original string isn't always the same (methods can be inherited from different classes) so a simple replacement will not work

Required format:

```
IntArrayListTest:testReplaceFromToWith() IntArrayListTest:assertEquals(long,long)
IntArrayListTest:testRetainAllSmall() list.IntArrayList:<init>()
RandomUtilsTest:testNextTwinPrime() RandomUtils:nextTwinPrime(int)
OpenLongCharHashMapTest:testValues() CharArrayList:size()
```

Comment: What have you tried and what did not work?

Comment: .split('.')[-1] I have tried using split but I couldn't figure out an efficient way to do it as each line could have a different number classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open('input.txt') as fp:
    res = '\n'.join([' '.join([x.split('.')[-1] for x in line.strip().split()]) for line in fp])
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
IntArrayListTest:testReplaceFromToWith() IntArrayListTest:assertEquals(long,long)
IntArrayListTest:testRetainAllSmall() IntArrayList:<init>()
RandomUtilsTest:testNextTwinPrime() RandomUtils:nextTwinPrime(int)
OpenLongCharHashMapTest:testValues() CharArrayList:size()
FunctionTest:testIsDensifying() DoubleDoubleFunction:isDensifying()
```

Another Method:

```
with open('input.txt') as fp:
    res = ''
    for line in fp:
        x, y = line.strip().split()
        x, y = x.split(':'), y.split(':')
        x = x[1].split('.')[-1] + ':' + x[-1]
        y = y[0].split('.')[-1] + ':' + y[-1]
        res += x + ' ' + y + '\n'
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
IntArrayListTest:testReplaceFromToWith() IntArrayListTest:assertEquals(long,long)
IntArrayListTest:testRetainAllSmall() IntArrayList:<init>()
RandomUtilsTest:testNextTwinPrime() RandomUtils:nextTwinPrime(int)
OpenLongCharHashMapTest:testValues() CharArrayList:size()
FunctionTest:testIsDensifying() DoubleDoubleFunction:isDensifying()
VectorBinaryAssignTest:testAll() DoubleDoubleFunction:apply(double,double)
VectorBinaryAssignTest:testAll() PrintStream:printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object[])
```

Answer (score 0):

If the text to be removed is always exactly as above. You can do a simple replace.

```
with open("in.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        new_line = line.strip().replace("M:org.apache.mahout.math.list.","").\
                   replace("(S)org.apache.mahout.math.list.","").\
                   replace("(O)org.apache.mahout.math.list.","")

        print(new_line)
```

Or if there is always ".math.list." before the function and " () in the middle, you can use split:

```
with open("in.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        new_line = line.strip().split(".math.list.")[1:]
        new_line = new_line[0].split("() ")[0]+"() "+ new_line[1]
        print(new_line)
```

Otherwise, RegEx are your best option

Output:

```
IntArrayListTest:testReplaceFromToWith() IntArrayListTest:assertEquals(long,long)
IntArrayListTest:testRetainAllSmall() IntArrayList:<init>()
IntArrayListTest:testRemoveAll() IntArrayListTest:assertEquals(long,long)
```

Comment: Sorry I'll edit my question to clarify that. It's not always the same string so you can't do a simple replace

Comment: @KiP Is the number of periods always the same on every line?

Comment: No, periods vary from 3-5. I have considered almost every brute force method.

Comment: @KiP I've added another code to my answer, if .math.list. and () are always in the line you can use split as shown in the code above. Let us know if it works

Comment: math.list isn't always there. could be ```M:org.apache.mahout.math.FunctionTest:testIsDensifying() (M)org.apache.mahout.math.function.DoubleDoubleFunction:isDensifying()```

Comment: How would I use regex to match all these variations?